# Ошибка при обращении к базе данных "column '_id' does not exist"

Tags: android, sqlite, cursoradaper

Есть два активити. В одном заполняется два поля, затем они через `Extras` передаются в первое активити. В первом находится `listview`, который должен отображать данные из базы. Что может быть не так?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etFindNote;
    ListView list;
    Button btnAdd, btnMenu;
    final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    final String ATTRIBUTE_DATE = "date";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NOTE = "note";

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etFindNote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFindNote);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] from = new String[] {"data", "note"};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.itemDate, R.id.itemNote};

        cursor = db.query("mytable", from, null, null, null, null, null);

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, cursor, from, to);

        list.setAdapter(scAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(list);
    }

    public void NewNoteClick (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                cv.put("data", intent.getStringExtra("data"));
                cv.put("note", intent.getStringExtra("note"));

                db.insert("myDB", null, cv);
            }
        }
    }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
        + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + "date text,"
        + "note text"+");");
    }
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    }
}
}
```

Логи

```
    01-11 23:21:57.930 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: определяем элементы
    01-11 23:21:57.930 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: создаем бд
    01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: создаем курсор для чтения
    01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: определяем массивы для чтения
    01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: Считывам базу дннх в логи
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 1, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 2, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 3, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 4, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 5, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 6, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 7, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 8, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 9, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: id = 10, date = 07.05.2017, note = Hello
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: Закончили считывать в логи
01-11 23:21:57.940 28125-28125/? E/myLogs: передаем курсор адаптеру
01-11 23:21:57.950 28125-28125/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.alex.notes, PID: 28125
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alex.notes/com.example.alex.notes.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:163)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
                                                       at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
                                                       at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:172)
                                                       at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:149)
                                                       at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:91)
                                                       at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:104)
                                                       at com.example.alex.notes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1371) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5595) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Напишите, что конкретно не так работает. Вы описали только то, как должна работать программа. А что с ней не так - кто ж его знает=)

Comment: При данном коде приложение вылетает при запуске

Comment: @AlexAlex Если приложение вылетает, то нужны еще логи (вкладка LogCat Вашей Android Studio)

Comment: Логи прикрепил)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist` говорит нам о том, что база данных в Android-приложении обязательно должна содержать колонку уникального ключа с именем *_id* (не id, ID, _ID или как то еще) и атрибутом `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` для корректной работы классов, связанных с SQLite.

```
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
    + "_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
    + "date text,"
    + "note text"+");");
}
```

Так же колонка *_id* обязательно должна быть включена в выборку курсора.

**Внимание:** Для изменения структуры БД теперь недостаточно просто исправить имя колонки, так как БД создается один раз при старте и только если файл БД отсутствует на устройстве, а дальше ее структуру можно изменить только через метод `onUpgrade()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` с повышением версии БД, однако для тестового приложения достаточно просто **удалить** это **приложение с** тестирующего **устройства**, тогда база будет удалена вместе с ним и при следующем запуске БД будет создана заново уже с исправлениями.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!