# Как получить ID ряда из ListView с данными SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

В моем приложении для хранения данных используется `Sqlite`. В таблице несколько столбцов, один из которых `title`. Данные из этого столбца передаются в `ArrayList`, который в свою очередь передается  в адаптер `ListView`. Таким образом, на экране телефона появляется список из столбца `title`. При длительном нажатии на один item `ListView` появляется контекстное меню, через которое нужно удалить из базы данных ряд, `title` которого находится в `item'е`. 
Я второй день ломаю голову над тем, как сделать удаление. Когда вызывается контекстное меню, можно узнать позициию   `item'а`, над которым оно было вызвано. Но для удаления нужна не позиция, а `id` ряда. Как мне реализовать удаление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, Вы воспользовались стандартным адаптером для списка ListView. который хранит только строковые переменные. Вы можете написать свой адаптер для ListView со своим сложным объектом. Свои объекты вы можете индексировать с помощью клаcса UUID, который представляет собой уникальный идентификатор:

```
public class Product {

 public String name;
 public int price;
 public int image;
 public UUID ID; //уникальный идентификатор
}

Product(String _describe, int _price, int _image) {
 name = _describe;
 price = _price;
 image = _image;
 ID = UUID.randomUUID(); //создаём уникальный идентификатор для объекта
}
```

По идентификатору вы можете легко удалять элементы из БД и из ListView.
Подробнее о том, как работать с ListView можно посмотреть [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html) и [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/85-urok-44-sobytija-v-listview.html).
Также, в книге [Android. Программирование для профессионалов 
Билл Филлипс, К. Стюарт, Кристин Марсикано](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/141049718/) есть целая глава, которая описывает управление объектами в БД.

Comment: Благодаря вам я не начал седеть.

Comment: каким образом этот уникальный идентификатор будет связан с ID, автогенерируемым базой данных? и вообще вся эта схема - решение проблем, которых не должно быть при правильной организации архитектуры (то есть подпирание одних костылей другими)

Answer (score 1):

Первое, о чем вам следует хорошо подумать - дублирование данных (перемещение их из `Cursor` в `ArrayList`) несет за собой [только проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345), бессмысленный расход ресурсов и двойные операции по обслуживанию списка-дубликата и данных в БД. От этого надо избавится (варианты по ссылке выше).

Далее, непосредственно по вашему вопросу по получению ID кликнутой записи. При использовании адаптера, предназначенного для работы непосредственно с данными в виде `Cursor` - `SimpleCursorAdapter`, колбэк на клик по айтему (`OnItemClickListener`, `OnItemLongClickListener`) четвертым аргументом возвращает ID кликнутой строки в базе данных:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}
```

или для долгого клика:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   return true;
}
```

*long id* - ID записи в БД по айтему в списке которого кликнули/ По этому ID вы можете производить любые манипуляции с кликнутой записью в БД.

Чтобы все это работало, таблицы в БД обязательно должны иметь автоинкрементируемый [столбец с именем *_id*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769677/177345)

Так же хотел бы обратить внимание на [способ обновления списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806498/177345) с данными в виде курсора (первая часть ответа) и на современное решение взаимодействия данных и виджетов в виде списка (вторая часть ответа), которое имеет несколько важных преимуществ.