# по значению и имени столбца выбрать название таблиц

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть 2 таблицы:

tab1

```
|id - length|

|1- 0.5|
|2- 0.6|
|3- 0.7|
```

Связанная внешним ключом со второй:

tab2

```
|id-  diam- cap  - id_length|

|1- 6-  0.0013 -    1|

|2- 7-  0.0019- 1|

|3- 6-  0.0025- 2|

|4- 6-  0.0032- 3|
```

Надо по значению с первой таблицы вытащить данные из второй. Просто таких связанных таблиц есть очень много. А мне нужно, чтоб запрос происходил динамически через значение length из первой таблицы (основной).

Answer (score 0):

```
String table = "tab1"; // динамическое имя первой таблицы
String table2 = "tab2"; // имя второй таблицы
String column1 = table2 + ".diam"; // динамическое название столбца в таблице
String column2 = table2 + ".cap"; 
Cursor cursor = rawQuery("SELECT " + column1 + " , " + column2 + " FROM " + table + " , " + table2 + " WHERE " + table + ".id = " + table2 + ".id_length", null);
```

Получим значение колонки tab2.diam и tab2.cap у которой id_length = id из таблицы tab1

Так же вам нужно [обязательно иметь колонку *_id*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769677/177345) в таблицах (а не id)

Comment: Раз запрос формируется через конкантенацию, то мб лучше через String.format составить?

Comment: @gil9red в решении данного вопроса это не принципиально. Я показал наиболее наглядное решение, как реализовать в конкретном случае каждый программист может сделать выбор сам.