# Android: _id not found

Tags: android, sqlite

Проблема заключается в ошибке

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.miniplaceguide/com.example.miniplaceguide.activity_findplace}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'placename' does not exist
...//another-files
at com.example.miniplaceguide.activity_findplace.onResume(activity_findplace.java:48)
```

Сама колонка в БД есть, но решить проблему с ней  не могу (нуб в android-разработке)

Код формы:

```
package com.example.miniplaceguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import static com.example.miniplaceguide.databaser.COLUMN_NAME;


public class activity_findplace extends AppCompatActivity {


    databaser sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    ListView userList;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_findplace);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userList);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        sqlHelper = new databaser(getApplicationContext());
        sqlHelper.create_db();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            db = sqlHelper.open();
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select _id from place", null);
            String[] headers = new String[]{COLUMN_NAME};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

            // если в текстовом поле есть текст, выполняем фильтрацию
            if(!editText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                userAdapter.getFilter().filter(editText.getText().toString());

            // установка слушателя изменения текста
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
                // при изменении текста выполняем фильтрацию
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    userAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
            });

            // устанавливаем провайдер фильтрации
            userAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
                @Override
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        return db.rawQuery("select _id, placename from place", null);
                    }
                    else {
                        return db.rawQuery("select _id, placename from place where placename like ?", new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
                    }
                }
            });

            userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){}
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // Закрываем подключение и курсор
        db.close();
        userCursor.close();
    }

    public void resultar(View view){
        OpenResult();
    }

    public void OpenResult(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity_result.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Прошу помочь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/769677/177345

Comment: В таблице использован этот код:

CREATE TABLE "place" (
 "_id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 "city_id" integer NOT NULL,
 "placename" text NOT NULL,
 "placeinfo" text,
 "image" blob,
 "mapx" real,
 "mapy" real,
 FOREIGN KEY("city_id") REFERENCES "city"("_id")
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я давненько не использовал SimpleCursorAdapter, но есть подозрение, что в

```
userCursor = db.rawQuery("select _id from place", null);
```

нужно выбрать не только id. Добавьте туда placename. О чем говорится, кстати, вот тут

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'placename' does not exist
```

Или вообще сделайте

```
select _id, * from place
```